# htaccess RewriteRule generate url with 2 parameters in any order

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, url-rewriting

I have this url with 2 parameters

```
https://mywebsite.com/folder/subfolder/page.php?id=999&title=this-is-a-test
```

and I need a rule to generate the following url

```
https://mywebsite.com/page/this-is-a-test-999/
```

I tried this rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^-]*)-([^-]*)/$ /folder/subfolder/page.php?&id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

and I get this url

```
https://mywebsite.com/page/999-this-is-a-test/
```

what changes I need to do in the rule to get

```
this-is-a-test-999
```

instead of

```
999-this-is-a-test
```

any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The `RewriteRule` you show will do the opposite of what you describe. If you visit a URL like `/page/this-is-a-test-999/`, the rule will serve content from `/folder/subfolder/page.php?title=this-is-a-test&id=999`. The rule you have here will do nothing if you visit a URL like those "type 1" or "type 2" URLs with `page.php`.  Can you edit your question and clarify?

Comment: As @Don'tPanic said you will need to revise your question to demonstrate what your actual situation is and what changes you want to implement. Please be precise: what are the URL of the incoming requests and what do your want them to be rewriiten ir redirected to? This is indeed not clear from your question, you contradict yourself currently.

Comment: question edited! :)

Comment: Your edit didn't change anything in terms of what you describe being the opposite of what the rule will do.  Are you maybe copy-pasting small sections of the full `.htaccess`?  If so, the pieces copied here are not the pieces doing what you say is happening.  Nothing in your question makes sense - eg the rule will not even change the URL shown in the browser (for that you would need an `R` in the flags section at the end of the rule).

Comment: Think of the rule syntax as `RewriteRule from to`.  You can see that the from/to URLs in the rule are the opposite of what you say is happening.  [I found an `.htaccess` tester](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/), maybe it will help.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as in its current form it is not clear what you have, what you need, or what you are seeing, and it cannot be answered as-is .  Please either edit it to clarify or close.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule ( /page/this-is-a-test-999/ <> /folder/subfolder/page.php?&id=999&title=this-is-a-test )

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page\/(.*)-(\d+)\/$ /folder/subfolder/page.php?&id=$2&title=$1 [L]
```